# Where does Runkeeper keep its data files?

Tags: gps, gps-tracking, file-system

I was recording my path with Runkeeper for hours until the battery ran out. Now when I try to "Resend" the path to Runkeeper online it fails after a while.

I need to find the path file so I can import it onto my PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data files are usually kept in either /data/data/[packagename]/ or they could be stored on the sdcard.

[packagename] will be something like **com.fitnesskeeper.runkeeper.pro**. The data file your looking for will probably be in that directory (well, one of the sub-directories any how).

As for if they store the data on the sdcard, most developers do not follow the recommendations to store the data in /sdcard/Android/ so if they are on the sdcard, I couldn't tell you where to even look. I would suggest, after you look in /data/data, to look for the [packagename] some where on the sdcard, or look for something with runkeeper in the name.